# Weird rb.velocity.y

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I'm moving left or right rb.velocity.y changes to weird numbers. How can I get rid of this?
I want to change the gravity when player is jumping and because of this bug it changes even if player is moving left and right.

```
    void FixedUpdate(){

        isGrounded = Physics2D.BoxCast(coll.bounds.center,coll.bounds.size, 0, Vector2.down, .1f,WhatIsGround);

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        if(jumped){
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jump, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            jumped = false;
        }

        if(rb.velocity.y < 0){
            rb.gravityScale = fallMultiplier;
        }
        else if(rb.velocity.y > 0 && !(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))){
            rb.gravityScale = lowJumpMultiplier;
        }
        else{
            rb.gravityScale = 1f;
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Well surely velocity y changes when you jump... that would be expected behavior

Comment: [tag:unityscript] is a programming language that has been deprecated a long time ago and does not appear in this question. removing the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both floating point calculations and Unity physics aren't precise. When your Rigidbody is moving, the gravity is trying to push it into the ground collider, while collision detection is pushing it upwards. This results in tiny oscillations in velocity.

You should never use direct comparison when working with float values. In this case, you need a small threshold to reliably detect the Y velocity direction:

```
if(rb.velocity.y < -.1f)
{
    rb.gravityScale = fallMultiplier;
}
else if (rb.velocity.y > .1f && !(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)))
{
    rb.gravityScale = lowJumpMultiplier;
}
else 
{
    rb.gravityScale = 1f;
}
```

Comment: @TomekSolender This answer solved the question in the post, right? Consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) this answer and ask your new question in a [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).